# activate an event on the button only after the animation has finished

Tags: jquery, animation

I create a button that when it is clicked, moves some images but when I **click quickly** the button, jQuery create an **error on the movement** of the images. So I want **disable the button** untill that the .animate() function isn't finish. I tryed write this code but isn't correct.

```
var next = $('.next');

function nextAction(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    next.off('click');
    if(pellicle.css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') <= -(stepTotalWidth - screenWidth)){
        pellicle.animate({
            left:'0'
        },1000, function(){next.on('click', nextAction);});
    }
    else {
        pellicle.animate({
            left:'-=' + screenWidth
        },1000);
    }
}

next.on('click', nextAction);
```

Comment: my code dosen't work, in the sense that it dosen't disable the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach and detach events as many as you want, i didn't get what is the question exept that you have o problem with click in period when you 'off' event while animation running.

For this you can attach another event that will prevent default and second will run animanion

```
function nextAction(e){
    next.off('click.gallery'); //detach by namespace
    next.off('click', nextAction); //detach by link on function

    //Your code and again attach animation click
}


next.on('click', function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
});

next.on('click.gallery', nextAction); 
/* .gallery is not necessary if you will detach events 
by the link on the function that attached to that */
```

The second thing is that `pellicle.css('left')` is always returns ***px in that case a bit faster than regexp would be `parseInt(pellicle.css('left'), 10) || 0` it will always give you a number in that case.

Comment: the question is how I do detach an event when the animation start and after that animation is finish how I can do attach the event.

I want detach an event on button for the iPhone slides.
http://matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution by Flops, here there is complete code

```
//next button
function nextAction(e){
    next.off('click', nextAction); //detach by link on function
    e.preventDefault();
    if(parseInt(pellicle.css('left')) <= -(stepTotalWidth - screenWidth)){
        pellicle.animate({
            left:'0'
        },1000, function(e){next.on('click', nextAction);});
    }
    else {
        pellicle.animate({
            left:'-=' + screenWidth
        },1000, function(e){next.on('click', nextAction);});
    }
}
next.on('click', nextAction);
```